# Forzar https en proyecto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

tengo un proyecto laravel y quiero que solo se acceda por **https** no por http

En el archivo .htaccess dentro de public/ tengo este código

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

A pesar de esto puedo acceder a mi dominio por http://, me gustaria que me redireccionase

No se si poner este código dentro del .htaccess anterior

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitio.com/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo hecho así:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    #First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tudominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    #Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tudominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Y luego en el fichero .env el parámetro `APP_URL=https.tudominio.com` para que los links sean con htpps.

Comment: Gracias, solucionado 1000 gracias !!!

Comment: Yo creo que si, que te mandará a https, otra cosa será si el navegador pondrá el candado o te mostrará un aviso de que el certificado no es de fiar...